# Using a DDL Inside Edit Templete of a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

first off i am very new to programing so bear with me.

I was able to get a drop down list to work inside the inserting template by doing the following.

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAprt" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                            <asp:ListItem>Check</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Ok</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Repaired</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Replaced</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
</InsertItemTemplate>




protected void ListView1_ItemInserting(object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlProjectManager = (DropDownList)ListView1.EditItem.FindControl("ddlAprt");
        if (ddlProjectManager != null)
            e.Values["Aprt"] = ddlProjectManager.SelectedValue;
    }
```

FYI, MY database is going to have number of columns (20+). To limit selection  all but one (primary key) is going using ddl like I did above.  So i play to use that code over and over again.

So  i need the same functionally but on the EditItemTemplete.

I have some worries on this.
When they insert the items the first time, they will not change all the ddl. 
Because of this i have check item in the ddl  working like a null field. 
When they go to edit, the ones that have been moved off check, need to stay there. So they don't accidentally update the items they didn't work on back to check (nothing would get done).

In plain English,  they are going to be updating rows they worked on. They are going to access the webpage. Select Edit, and find one of the rows that hasn't been finished. Edit that row using a ddl, and click update. The rows they didn't work on go back into the db as they where. The one's they worked on is updated to be something other then "check".

So how do i go about doing this? 
I have checked the following sites. Here are some examples which are doing something similar 
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/17/10251820/how-to-bound-values-to--dropdownlist-in-gridview--edit-item-template.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewdataitem%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

one last thing, i am using SQL data source. Would really like to keep it that way.
Easier the better

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks that solved my problemm, but know when ever click insert i get

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just bind to the drop down list:

```
<EditItemTemplate> 
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAprt" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Aprt")%>'>
<asp:ListItem>Check</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Ok</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Repaired</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Replaced</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

You should be able to use this same bind statement in your insert template also, then you wouldn't need that code in your codebehind page.